# Ionic: Error Initializing Cordova class not found

Tags: android, html, ionic-framework

I have added config file in res folder of my ionic project.
This is the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG"/>
  <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  <plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
  <feature name="Whitelist">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.whitelist.WhitelistPlugin"/>
    <param name="onload" value="true"/>
  </feature>
  <feature name="Camera">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher"/>
  </feature>
  <feature name="File">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils"/>
    <param name="onload" value="true"/>
  </feature>
  <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
  <name>HelloCordova</name>
  <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
  <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="*"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
  <plugins>
    <plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
</plugins>
</widget>
```

It is also added in the root folder of my ionic project

I have also added Content Security Provider to my index.html and this is the content:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

I have also added and removed android platforms but when I run my app I get ERROR Initialing Cordova: Class not found. My solution also founds it dificult accessing the internet.
Come to my rescue.

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution:

```
cordova platform rm android
```

Thereafter I installed a new cordova

```
npm install -g cordova
```

Thereafter I added a new platform

```
cordova platform add android
```

Then added all my plugins with the command

```
cordova plugin add (plugin name)
```

I also ensured that config.xml is in my res/xml folder.
Then I was good to go!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on ubuntu.

I had to change the permission on Cordova executable :

```
which cordova
/user/local/bin/cordova
sudo chown my_user /user/local/bin/cordova
```